# Zurb Foundation Flexbox 6.6.3 & Flot/Flex Grid not working

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am testing out moving from Bootstrap 4 to Zurb Foundation. However, I am finding that some stuff that Bootstrap has doesn't seem to be available in Foundation.

It seems the XY Grid is the latest and greatest.

I want to align the paragraph inside the cell, but only when the cell is at a large width. Can this be done? I can not find anything in their documentation for the XY Grid to support this.

```
<div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
    <div class="cell large-4 large-align-self-bottom">
        <p>Hello world</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Therefore, tried to use the Flex Grid instead. However, after downloading this grid version, there isnt even a reference to `.row` `.columns` on the foundation.min.css

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="columns small-6">6 columns</div>
  <div class="columns small-6">6 columns</div>
</div>
```

What's going on with it?!

Comment: First, which files did you use or how did you install Foundation Sites. Second, you can create custom classes or take at thr prototyping classes and use the needed breakpoints to achieve this.

Comment: The default release uses XY Grid. To switch to Flex Grid you have to use the Sass version and generate it by changing the grid settings.